# Pandas groupby with unique values and cumulative sum

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I have got the following dataframe:

```
lst=[['2021','01012021','A','AA',2],['2021','01012021','B','BB',4],['2021','01022021','A','AA',6],['2021','01032021','B','BB',8],['2021','01032021','B','BB',10],['2022','01012022','A','AA',3],['2022','01012022','C','CC',6],['2022','01022022','A','AA',9],['2022','01022022','C','CC',12]]
df1=pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['YEAR','Month','P1','P2','AuM'])
```

For each year and each month it should accumulate the AuM of all unique P1 and P2. The result should look like this:

```
lst=[['2021','01012021','A','AA',2],['2021','01012021','B','BB',4],['2021','01022021','A','AA',8],['2021','01022021','B','BB',4],['2021','01032021','A','AA',16],['2021','01032021','B','BB',14],['2022','01012022','A','AA',3],['2022','01012022','C','CC',6],['2022','01022022','A','AA',12],['2022','01022022','C','CC',18]]
df2=pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['YEAR','Month','P1','P2','AuM_YTD'])`
```

Even if in the the year 2021, 01.02.2021 there wasn't any AuM for P1=b and P2=bb the AuM was still shown from other months.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you explain how you got 4 on index number 3 for AuM_YTD?

Comment: I Scott. I the second month (01.02.2021) there wasn't any P1 = B and P2= BB, thus there is no AuM value to add in the second period. However, the AuM Value coming from the first period (01.01.2021) should be appear in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The exact grouping rules are unclear (thus the slightly different output), but the general idea is to to use [`groupby`+`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
                              # month+year        # other groups
df1['AuM_YTD'] = df1.groupby([df1['Month'].str[2:] ,'P1', 'P2'])['AuM'].cumsum()
```

output:

```
   YEAR     Month P1  P2  AuM  AuM_YTD
0  2021  01012021  A  AA    2        2
1  2021  01012021  B  BB    4        4
2  2021  01022021  A  AA    6        6
3  2021  01032021  B  BB    8        8
4  2021  01032021  B  BB   10       18
5  2022  01012022  A  AA    3        3
6  2022  01012022  C  CC    6        6
7  2022  01022022  A  AA    9        9
8  2022  01022022  C  CC   12       12
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. However, I am still looking to get the same answer as df2, which accumulates the AuM for all unique P1 and P2 month by month for each year.